# h2o deep learning NN 1 layer non reproducing X + Y = Z

Tags: r, h2o

I have just started using the h2o package in order to build a supervised NN network wit the deeplearning package.
In order to get a bit on track I started trying to simulate a function like X + Y = Z

**My code is the following:**

```
data <- read.table("DeepLearningTest.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "", stringsAsFactor = F)

test <- read.table("DeepLearningTestRun.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "", stringsAsFactor = F)

   df <- data.frame (data)
   tf <- data.frame (test)
   h2o.init ()
   hf <- as.h2o (df)

m2 <- h2o.deeplearning(
  training_frame=hf, 
  x=0:1,
  y='C',
  hidden = c(100),             
  epochs=100000,                    
  stopping_tolerance=0.001
)

h2o.predict (m2, as.h2o(tf))
```

**Where my test samples are the following (for example):**

1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 6
4 4 8
. . .
until
2000 2000 4000

In general is X + X = 2X

The thing I am not understanding and for which I am writing is that, if I use one layer network (for the univeral approximation theorem should be sufficient)
I can traing the network and the predict quite good values in the range of the prediction.

for instance the network is giving me

100 100 200
101 101 202
7 7 14

but when I put 
4000 4000

the result is misleading. It gives me something like 6300
It seems that the network is not able to generalized.
What am I doing wrong to make this behavior?

Thank you for you attention.

Regards,
Nicola